# Private git repo with self-signed certificate as Concourse resource

Tags: git, self-signed, concourse, concourse-git-resource

Please explain how to make use of a private Git repo with a **self-signed certificate** as resource in Concourse.

(I know about this accepted [feature request](https://github.com/concourse/concourse/issues/1027) but I - and others probably as well - prefer the concise answer.)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Git resource (https://github.com/concourse/git-resource)

About the **self-signed certificate**, use the  `skip_ssl_verification` option in the `Source` section.